# When I'm going to install ThreeJs on my vs code its not connecting to internet

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i m going to install **ThreeJs** to my project using `npm install --save three` nut my VS Code not connected to internet and it gives error down below what can i do to solve this problem

```bash
PS D:\\ThreeJSLearning\> npm install --save three
```

> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
>
> npm ERR! syscall connect
>
> npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
>
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/three failed,
> reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1c22:443
>
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad
> network settings.
>
> npm ERR! network
>
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help
> config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-07T06_34_56_846Z-debug-0.log

1. I checked my terminal connection using ping to google.com but all packets receive = 0

   ```
   PS D:\ThreeJSLearning> ping google.com

   Pinging google.com [2404:6800:4003:c00::65] with 32 bytes of data:
   Request timed out.
   Request timed out.
   Request timed out.
   Request timed out.

   Ping statistics for 2404:6800:4003:c00::65:
       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
   ```
2. I Reload My Window and restart my computer